# Store custom data maps as attributes within ServletContext?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, jersey-2.0

I was looking for a way to load some data from DB into a HashMap and make that map available for all root resource classes and some additional provider classes (implementation of ContainerRequestFilter to be more precise). I found and implemented a solution where I execute a query and load the map within a contextInitialized method of ServletContextListener and set it as an ServletContext attribute:

```
@WebListener
public class ServletContextCaching implements ServletContextListener {

    @Inject
    private SomeBeanLocalInterface someBean;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        context.removeAttribute("CUSTOM_DATA_MAP");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        List<SomeEntity> someEntities = someBean.findAllActive();
        Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (SomeEntity e : someEntities) {
            temp.put(e.getSomeKey(), e.getSomeValue());
        }
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        context.setAttribute("CUSTOM_DATA_MAP", temp);

    }

}
```

Is it good practice to store custom data (i.e. attributes) within servlet context and thus make it available for "everyone"? What is the suggested practice for loading some data from DB into memory maps within REST services? I am pretty sure I am not the first one needing this :)

Comment: I don't think it should be inside the servlet. You should probably have a singleton instance of a bean which contains this data, which can be injected into any service that needs it. The bean itself would need the data source injecting into it so it can read from it when it's constructed. If you look at your injection framework for how it constructs singletons you may find the answer drops out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing data with an application scope is very common. You could use the `ServletContext` but there are other alternatives. As Ashley Frieze already commented you can use one instance of a bean and inject it where needed. This would be e.g. an `@ApplicationScoped` bean if you use CDI or a `@Singleton` bean if you use EJBs.

If you want a pure JAX-RS solution without any dependencies you can use `@Context` like [described by Bill Burke](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2011/03/09/adding-objects-that-are-context-injectable/). Here's a copy of the example:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public MyApplication(@Context Dispatcher dispatcher) {
        MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
        dispatcher.getDefaultContextObjects().put(MyClass.class, myInstance);
    }

 }
```

You can than inject your class like this:

```
public void get(@Context MyClass myInstance) { ... }
```

If you have a huge amount of data to be stored a distributed cache like [infinispan](http://infinispan.org/) or [hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com/) may also be an option. But may be oversized for most use cases.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. @Ashley Frieze, thank you also. I like the first alternative - creating an application scoped bean and injecting it where needed. But, while this works nice for root resource classes I can not get it to work within a class implementing ContainerRequestFilter. Injected variable (instance of application scoped bean) is always null in this filter.

Comment: This is working for me. Is your Filter annotated as `@Provider`?

Comment: It is annotated as @Provider but the injected variable is null. It should definitely work, there must be a problem specific to my project. That is my problem now, I will find the error. Regarding the question here, it's answered (both opinion and alternatives offered). Thank you for your help and advice.